# angular2 append component to a native element created with renderer

Tags: angular, reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to port https://draftjs.org/ to angular, I'm now at the [contents](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/tree/master/src/component/contents) part, which basically takes the [model](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#content) and turns it back into html.

I'm now stuck at these lines in particular https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/component/contents/DraftEditorContents.react.js#L172-L192, what happens there, as far as I can tell, is that react is creating an element depending on element type from the model, so for a simple text it's gonna be a [`div`](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/16ed6e5a1e7c9d5a0d5718b9a50c8256ee33f938/src/model/immutable/DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.js#L63-L66), for heading `h1` etc., and as a child of this element it appends a component which then deals with rendering of the actual content, whether it's just a text or user provided decorator component.

I think the first part is required to get things like lists(ul, ol) working (thus the [grouping by the same wrapper](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/16ed6e5a1e7c9d5a0d5718b9a50c8256ee33f938/src/component/contents/DraftEditorContents.react.js#L205)), you can't just start with a component at at root. Now as far as I can tell, every technique that allows to add dynamic components in angular requires either `ViewContainerRef` or `ngComponentOutlet`, none of which is possible when you do

```
const child = this._renderer.createElement(Element);
this._renderer.appendChild(this._elementRef.nativeElement, child)
```

is it? I was also thinking about simply hardcoding all the root elements in the html and then using `ngComponentOutlet`, but then it wouldn't allow for [custom renderers](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map.html#content) I think.

PS: draftjs is pretty darn complex project, I got the model part ported to typescript and working, if there is anyone interested and willing on cooperating with the content rendering part, I'll be more than glad

Comment: `draftjs` not support mobile browser, this is the key point to stop it be really popular.

Comment: Somewhat tangentially if anyone’s interested, lib ngx-draft-js wraps Draft.js as an Angular component. Your app will have to include react & react-dom packages, which might not be an issue on client-facing pages with lower performance requirements. Disclaimer: I wrote it and I use it in some of my clients’ apps.

Comment: so I heard, people including react just to get this functionality, crazy... follow https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4444, we might get a proper angular version one day

Comment: @fxck I have a very similar use case and encounterd the same issue. Could you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @kervantas sorry, no

Comment: Since than I gave up and rewrote my app in Svelte. No VDOM no worries.